# Integration by parts of the Laplacian

Tags: vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

This is something that every text book or notes skips to explain in the derivation of the LSZ reduction formula

Suppose we have $$
a_{1}^{\dagger} \equiv \int d^{3} k f_{1}(\mathbf{k}) a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k})
$$
where
$$
f_{1}(\mathbf{k}) \propto \exp \left[-\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_{1}\right)^{2} / 4 \sigma^{2}\right]
$$
is an appropriate wave packet, and $\sigma$ is its width in momentum space.

In the derivation of LSZ reduction formula at certain point in this notes [Quantum Field Theory](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/ms-qft-DRAFT) by Mark Srednicki at page 50
they have
\begin{aligned}
 &-i \int d^{3} k f_{1}(\mathbf{k}) \int d^{4} x e^{i k x}\left(\partial_{0}^{2}-\overleftarrow{\nabla}^{2}+m^{2}\right) \phi(x) \\
&=-i \int d^{3} k f_{1}(\mathbf{k}) \int d^{4} x e^{i k x}\left(\partial_{0}^{2}-\overrightarrow{\nabla}^{2}+m^{2}\right) \phi(x)
\end{aligned}

I am using this to proof it \begin{align*}
\int f(y)g''(y)dy &= f(y)g'(y)| - \int g'(y)f'(y)dy\\
\int g(y)f''(y)dy &= g(y)f'(y)| - \int f'(y)g'(y)dy\quad\text{so}\\
\int f(y)g''(y)dy - \int g(y)f''(y)dy &= f(y)g'(y)| - g(y)f'(y)|.\\
\end{align*}

If we take the $x$ part of the Laplacian we  would  have
\begin{align*}
\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{dr^3 \left(\partial_x^2 e^{-ikr}\right)\phi}=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{dr^3 \ e^{-ikr} \partial_x^2\phi}+\left[e^{-ik_xx}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{dydze^{-ik_yy-ik_zz}\partial_x\phi}+\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{dydzik_xe^{-ikr}\left[\phi\right]^{x=\infty}_{x=-\infty}}.
\end{align*}

Now if we assume that $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}{\phi}=\lim_{r\rightarrow -\infty}{\phi}=0$ we have that $$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{dydzik_xe^{-ikr}\left[\phi\right]^{x=\infty}_{x=-\infty}}=0.$$

But what about the term

$$\left[e^{-ik_xx}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}{dydze^{-ik_yy-ik_zz}\partial_x\phi}.$$

why it is zero?

Comment: Strictly speaking you have to assume more about the behavior of $\phi$ for large $r$... only if it goes to zero fast enough can you show that the RHS vanishes in the appropriate limit.

Comment: @mjqxxxx assuming that $\phi$ goes fast enough to zero how  can we proof that the RHS is zero

Comment: Then look at the integral for $r < R$, bound the surface term with a function of $R$ that goes to zero (because of how $\phi$ does), and take the limit $R \rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Bound the integrand on the sphere and see what inequalities get you for the surface integral.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664296/2451